# Cocoa app to publish podcasts vs Mobile friendly site

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, podcast

** Please don't migrate this to Apple - it won't be seen. Thanks.

I'm not sure of the legal implications of what I am trying to do, but here it goes.

There is a radio show that I love listening to. It comes on everyday and the podcasts are uploaded to a website so users can download and listen to them for free. The website isn't very navigable, however, and it's extremely hard to play the podcasts from my phone (and, therefore, my car).

I have a long commute and I would love it if I could either access these podcasts via some kind of iphone app or maybe even a mobile-friendly website. I am first trying to figure out which would be better (iphone app vs mobile friendly website) and how sketchy you think it would be for me to develop the app (or site) and then offer it to the radio show for them to upload their podcasts. Alternatively, if they didn't want it, I would just download the podcasts from the site and re-upload them to mine.

Please note I am not trying to make any money off this, I am only trying to make it easy for people like me (with long commutes) to enjoy this particular radio show without having to navigate the existing (dysfunctional) site- risking the lives of dogs, squirrels, and other drivers in the process.

Comment: which would be better for this project - iphone app or mobile friendly website

Comment: do this again and there will be consequences

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create an iPhone app, you will have more control over the OS-specific things that you can do but it will be limited to only the Apple platform.  If you create a mobile-friendly site, it will be accessible from any platform but it will be limited by what you can do with a browser.  I would say the target audience is the issue.  If your target is just you or you and your iPhone friends, do the app.  However, if you want scale, do the web app since it will reach the Android and WinPhone7 markets as well.